# Linearization of nonlinear system

Tags: non-linear, control-theory

I have a nonlinear system described by:

$$\begin{align}
 V\,\dot x_1 &= Q_1 C_1 - (Q_1+u)x_1 \\
 V\,\dot x_2 &= C_2\,u -(Q_1+u)x_2 \\
 y &= -\frac{\log{\left[(x_1-x_2)+|x_1-x_2|+4K\right]}}{2}
\end{align}$$

\$V\$, \$K\$, \$Q_1\$, \$C_1\$, \$C_2\$ are constants, \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ are states, \$y\$ is the output, and \$u\$ is the input.

Can I perform linearization to this system as a way to control it?
I want to linearize around let's say \$y_e=7\$ but then \$x_e\$ is not zero and I cannot form the linearized model since I have to take into account the \$y-y_e\$ or \$x-x_e\$ terms. What I mean is that when you linearize around zero everything is easy and in order. But when the equilibrium point is not zero, what do we do then?

Also, what is the order here? I linearize and construct a linearized model around \$x_e\$. Then, you control it with a control law.
Then, you apply the control law to the nonlinear system. Is that correct?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Is there a hidden EE question waiting to be released?

Answer (score 2):

Linearization can be performed at any point of a smooth curve, as long as the inputs don't perturb the output outside the linearized area.

My way of checking this would just be to simulate it in that range (phase space), and figure out the linear equation around that point.

Of course take this with a grain of salt. I feel that I've seen the equation for y somewhere before... Can't remember where though (depletion region of MOSFET perhaps..). From just looking at the equations it does not look like you have nonlinear memory effects, so you should be fine. The two first eqns just look like charge accumulation/capacitor differential equations.